# Autoscroll won't stop scrolling .js/jquery/ajax issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, livechat

My chat box won't stop autoscrolling (it won't let me scroll up), I know where the problem lies... however I don't know how to get around it. I need the chat box to autoscroll however I want to be able to scroll up at the same time.

Here's [a live example](http://goawaymom.com/) of the problem.

```
//Load the file containing the chat log
function loadLog(){     
    $("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: 99999 }, 'normal');
    $.ajax({
        url: "log.html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){        $("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: 99999 }, 'normal');
        $("#chatbox").html(html);
        $("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: 99999 }, 'normal');



        }               

    });
}
```

Comment: as a side note, instead of polling with AJAX repeatedly, have you thought of using websockets?

Comment: no, I don't even know what web sockets are. :s

Comment: Set a global variable maxScroll and on success of ajax, update only if scrollTop >= 99999.This should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check when the scoll position is. if it as the bottom then scroll to bottom

```
//Load the file containing the chat log
function loadLog(){     
  // remove  $("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: 99999 }, 'normal');
    $.ajax({
        url: "log.html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){     
        var chatbox= $("#chatbox");
        var atBottom = (chatbox[0].scrollHeight - chatbox.scrollTop() == chatbox.outerHeight());
        chatbox.html(html);

        if (atBottom )
         chatbox.animate({ scrollTop: 99999 }, 'normal');



        }               

    });
}
```